# Subscribe only available for AWS AppSync endpoint

Tags: reactjs, aws-appsync

I get issues when using @apollo/client: 3.5.10, aws-appsync:4.1.5.
There is my config

```
import { ApolloClient, ApolloLink, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { createAuthLink } from 'aws-appsync-auth-link';
import { createSubscriptionHandshakeLink } from 'aws-appsync-subscription-link';
// Config
import { AWS_APPSYNC } from '../config';

const { graphqlEndpoint, region, apiKey } = AWS_APPSYNC;
const auth = {
  type: AWS_APPSYNC.authenticationType,
  apiKey: apiKey,
};

const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri: graphqlEndpoint });
const link = ApolloLink.from([
  // @ts-ignore
  createAuthLink({ graphqlEndpoint, region, auth }),
  // @ts-ignore
  createSubscriptionHandshakeLink({ graphqlEndpoint, region, auth }, httpLink),
]);

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

and I am using

```
const {
    data: subscription_message_data,
    loading: subscription_message_loading,
    error: subscription_message_error
  } = useSubscription(
    SUBSCRIPTION_NEW_MESSAGE, {
      variables: { conversationId: conversationId }
    });
```

But I got an error form useSubscription is: "Subscribe only available for AWS AppSync endpoint"

Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue, and was baffled by this error message.
At the end the issue turned out to be the incorrect property name for the url used in the `createAuthLink` and `createSubscriptionHandshakeLink` input objects.

This was the fix that worked for me:

```
const link = ApolloLink.from([
  createAuthLink({ url: graphQLEndpoint, region, auth }),
  createSubscriptionHandshakeLink({ url: graphQLEndpoint, region, auth }, httpLink),
]);
```